# mysql find rows with array that have a similar item as search array

Tags: mysql

i want to find the rows that have at least i item in an array in common with my query array.

this is close to what i want:

```
SELECT *
    FROM Table
    WHERE column IN (1, 2, 3)
```

column contains data from an array stored as a string. for example:
i am looking for any row that has a 1,2 or 3 in it.

```
row 1.column = 1  
row 2.column = 3,6,7  
row 3.column = 8,9,10,11
```

i would like row 1 and row 2, but not row 3.

or, would it be better to store each item of array as a separate row?

Comment: I think you'll be better off storing the data per row in normalized form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would almost definitely be better to store as separate rows (see [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1553851)). If you do use a single column, you can query it using [`FIND_IN_SET()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set):

```
SELECT *
  FROM `table`
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(1, `column`)
    OR FIND_IN_SET(2, `column`)
    OR FIND_IN_SET(3, `column`);
```